# How to make a table using an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, tabular

I have an array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => "name" => "John","id" => "1"
    [1] => "name" => "Mary","id" => "2"
    [2] => "name" => "Sean","id" => "3"
)
```

How can I make a table like this:

```
1 | John
2 | Mary
3 | Sean
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried Milo? Show us your code, so we can help you on your way

Comment: you are getting a json, just use json_decode(..put everything here in quotes, true);

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the array and output all values as you want it formatted.

```
foreach($arr as $item){
    echo "$arr[id] | $arr[name]";
}
```

Or if its a HTML table you want

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($arr as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=  $arr['id'] ?> </td><td> <?= $arr['name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use shortcode for PHP opening tags. `<?=  ` http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php - see changelog

Comment: @Second2None `<?=` isn't a short open tag like `<?` it's a shorthand for `echo`, and it's always available regardless of the `short_open_tag` ini setting in any modern PHP version.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. Learn every day :)

Answer (score 1):

Asuming that the name of your arreglo is `$users`, you can loop through each element and output the data of that element in a row of the table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$user['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$user['name'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```